# Regarding jqplot plotting piechart with data from SQL server in php

Tags: php, sql, json, jqplot

Hi I am using jqplot for the first time. I need to show a pie chart by pulling data from database. I have written query and I am facing problems in converting the data in json table. I am not able to generate the graph.Please help me in this regard.This is my code.

PHP code

```
<?php require_once('Connections/finalkms.php'); 

mysql_select_db($database_finalkms, $finalkms);
$query_getdatagraoh = "SELECT Compliancestatus,value FROM COUNT_VALUE WHERE Zone='PZ' and country='AU' and `Compliancestatus` is not null";
$getdatagraoh = mysql_query($query_getdatagraoh, $finalkms) or die(mysql_error());
$row_getdatagraoh = mysql_fetch_assoc($getdatagraoh);
$totalRows_getdatagraoh = mysql_num_rows($getdatagraoh);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getdatagraoh)){ 
    $plotgraphs[] = array(
        $row['Compliancestatus'],
        $row['value']
    );
}
header('ContentType: application/json; charset=utf-8');
$data= json_encode($plotgraphs);
?>
```

java script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 var data1 = <?php echo json_encode($plotgraphs); ?>;
 alert(data1);
  var plot1 = jQuery.jqplot ('chart1', [data1], 
    { 
      seriesDefaults: {
        // Make this a pie chart.
        renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer, 
        rendererOptions: {
          // Put data labels on the pie slices.
          // By default, labels show the percentage of the slice.
          showDataLabels: true
        }
      }, 
      legend: { show:true, location: 'e' }
    }
  );
});

</script>
```

html

```
<div id="chart1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If 'Compliancestatus' field is not numeric you must use plugin "CategoryAxisRenderer"

```
xaxis:{
renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
}
```

And don't forget to import it!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
```